# Determine ajax call finished to run another ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

In my project I have some select option group which load ajax data depending on previous value. Now I am having problem when I am trying to copy them to another select option group.

here is the scenario

```
parmanet address              Present Address
Division                      Division    
District                      District
Upzilla                       Upzilla
Union                         Union
```

All of them are select field and after select each field next select option loaded by ajax. I put a checkbox and when user click the checkbox, parmanent address data should copy to present address with all the ajax call.

Now The problem is, the jquery "val" function not working because it runs before the data loaded from ajax. If I put delay to 100 ms, it working, but It's not a proper way. Is there any better way to solve this problem??

This is my code when i change division to load ajax data to division, and other option is same as like this.

```
$('#divisions').change(function() {
    $("#villtable").hide();
    $("#villaddform").hide();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'GetDistricts',
      data: {
        get_option:this.value
      },
      success: function(response) {
        document.getElementById("districts").innerHTML=response;
      }
    });
  });
```

And this is what i tried to copy data to present address group...

```
$.when( $('.division-prese').val(divi).trigger('change').delay( 100 ) ).then(function() {
    $.when( $('.district-prese').val(dist).trigger('change').delay( 100 ) ).then(function() {
        $.when( $('.upazilla-prese').val(upaz).trigger('change').delay( 100 ) ).then(function() {
                        $('.union-prese').val(unio).trigger('change');
        });   
    });
});
```

i also tried 'done', but still not working.

Comment: My initial thought about this issue is you shouldn't be forcing this logic through the generation of events.  Given your use case it would make sense to extract the ajax out of the change event into it's own method.  The change can call the method, and some other method can call it as well.  The other method would expect the ajax method to return the promise that it could then chain the second ajax call to.  Which would also return a promise which the third ajax call could be chained to.

Comment: If possible, will you please give me a example brother. It will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General idea of extracting the logic and using it in two places, one of which performing the promise chaining.

```js
function loadDistricts ($divisions) {
 return $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'GetDistricts',
  data: {
    get_option: $divisions.val()
  },
  success: function(response) {
   $('#districts').html(response);
  }
   });
}

//... other methods

var $divisions = $('#divisions');
var $districts = $('#districts');
var $upazillas = $('#upazillas');

$divisions.change(function() {
    $("#villtable").hide();
 $("#villaddform").hide();
 loadDistricts($divisions);
});

//... other change methods

$('.division-prese').val(divi);

loadDistricts($divisions).then(function(){
 $('.district-prese').val(dist);

 loadUpazillas($upazillas).then(function(){
  $('.upazilla-prese').val(upaz);

  //call next thing
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother for giving your valuable time and clear idea. Hope this will solve my issue. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score -1):

try adding return before your call

```
$('#divisions').change(function() {
    $("#villtable").hide();
    $("#villaddform").hide();
      return $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'GetDistricts',
      data: {
        get_option:this.value
      },
      success: function(response) {
        document.getElementById("districts").innerHTML=response;
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/66dsLj0z/1/  trigger() returns the jquery object it operates upon.  The deferred will not be returned from that event triggering.

Comment: You are right @Taplar . is there any api i can use instead of delay?